# Multiple fission and spore formation

Tags: reproduction, asexual-reproduction, algae

[image]

I came across this question today. In the B diagram, zoospores of chlamydomonas is given. Now my doubt is, are the zoospores formed by multiple fission or spore formation? If it is by spore formation, isn't spore formation and multiple fission the same thing when it comes to unicellular organism i.e chlamydomonas? If it is the same thing, why isn't option c correct in the question I attached?

Comment: I will answer later, so I can provide a good ref. The issue is whether this shows the result after fission (asexual)  or meiosis (sexual). Showing 9 daughter cells is a bit unfair..2,4,8,16 would be better. After meiosis the 4 daughter cells can also continue to divide by mitosis before release.

Comment: But zoospores are produced asexually, so meiosis isn't possible. Also is multiple fission produced by mitosis or amitosis?

Answer (score 2):

*All the organisms shown in the figure reproduce asexually. (A) is Penicillium in which non-motile conidia are produced singly or in chains. Organism (B) is Chlamydomonas in which reproduction occurs by zoospores. In Hydra (C) and yeast (D), asexual reproduction takes place by budding.*

Mutliple fission and Spore Formation are two distinct processes where in:

1. Multiple fission can be explained with the following diagram:
   [image]

Multiple fission is a process of asexual reproduction in which a single organism splits up into **multiple organisms or daughter cells of similar type** under favourable conditions like availibity of food and suitable environmental conditions.

2. Spore formation can be explained with the following diagram:
   [image]

Spores are **tiny microscopic hard unicellular sexual bodies** which are always suspended in air. Under suitable environmental conditions they settle down and grow into new plants. Above given is a structure of rhizopus(bread mould) reproducing through the process of spore formation. E*ach rhizopus consists of a globular structure at the top known as the sporangium which consists of spores. When the favourable conditions arrive then the sporangium bursts and the spores get suspended in the air. Soon they settle on the moist bread particles, leading to the formation of new rhizopus plants.*